# Gear menu in row themed Views

Tags: 7, views, users

Usually I need the contextual gear-icon menu that is missing from row-themed views. The tools provide a quick access to each node. So I insert `Content: Edit Link` field into the View and the template.

What kind of `if` should I put in the code to make the link accessible only by those authorized to edit the given node type?

Currently I have `if(user_is_logged_in()):` which is ok as a temporary solution, as the site does not create any users by itself, but we know this is not what should be there in the code.

Please remember: I do not want to control accessibility of an entire View, just the display of restricted field.

Comment: The edit link should automatically be shown/hidden based on the user's node access permissions. Is this not happening for you?

Comment: Grrrh... I'd swear it wasn't happening the other day I tried it, but now it's looking just the way you say. Strange. Glad it works.